# Show convergence in normed space

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

How do I show convergence in a normed space? I know a sequence is convergent if 
$$\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \, \exists n_\epsilon \in \mathbb N \, \forall n \geq n_\epsilon :\|x-x_n\| \lt \epsilon$$

---

But I am unsure how to apply this... Specifically in the following example:

Let $A_{n, m} :=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n+m+1}  & \text{if $m \leq n$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} $

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$; consider the sequence $(a_n)_{_{n \in \mathbb{N}}}$ in $\mathbb R^k$ with 
$$a_n := (A_{n,0}, ..., A_{n,k-1}) \in \mathbb R^k$$

Is $(a_n)_{_{n \in \mathbb{N}}}$ in $(\mathbb R^k, \|{\cdot}\|_\infty)$ convergent?

---

I also don't quite understand what $\|{\cdot}\|_1$, $\|{\cdot}\|_2$ and $\|{\cdot}\|_\infty$ etc mean.

I feel like I am generally quite shaky in this entire topic. Any help with this example would help me a lot to understand what I am supposed to do.

Comment: Waht can you say about the real sequence $(A_{n,i})$ for a fixed $i$?

Comment: Usually the norm with a $\infty$ subscript means it is defined by the supremum of the array. Did your book write about that?